# How to simultaneously maximize multiple likelihoods?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

This is a more generic question. Assuming I have closed-form likelihood functions of 2 related observations|distributions (for e.g. likelihood of observations from 2 MVN dists). However, because the likelihood isn't really bound like probability, I can't simply maximize the sum of the likelihood because one might be much larger than the other.

My question is, how do I simultaneously maximize both likelihood functions? Is there a way to normalize the likelihood (that seems pretty out there)? Yes, I understand, I can maximize each likelihood individually, however, assuming the 2 sharing some parameters and I would like to find optimal parameters for both. Any suggestion or related reading would help.

Comment: If they share some parameters and as such are not independent, the the idea is to find the joint likelihood and maximize it